Writing a powershell script to create a report that uses custom object and putting it all together
I am attempting to write a powershell script, I have made a start and I can see that the script is pulling back some data. However this is where i am stuck.
the script so far looks like this.
foreach ($clusterDS in Get-DataGatewayCluster | Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource) 
{
    $a = Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource -GatewayClusterId $clusterDS.ClusterId -GatewayClusterDatasourceId $clusterDS.Id 

    $clusterName = $clusterDS.ClusterName
    $DatasourceName = $clusterDS.DatasourceName
    $DatasourceType = $clusterDS.DatasourceType
    $ConnectionDetails = $clusterDS.ConnectionDetails
    $ClusterId = $clusterDS.ClusterId
    $clusterDSID = $clusterDS.Id

    $clusterName, $DatasourceName , $DatasourceType , $ConnectionDetails , $ClusterId, $clusterDSID
     
}


Next stage, pull all the data into a custom object that I can output as HTML within an email. When I have tried to do this, I get all sorts of errors.
The next problem is this.
I need to run the script.
Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasourceStatus -GatewayClusterId $ClusterId -GatewayClusterDatasourceId $clusterDSID
This cmdlet returns a value with the status i.e Live.
Ideally, I would like to return the status of all the data clusters, including the status
in this code snippet below
foreach ($clusterDS in Get-DataGatewayCluster | Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource) 
{
     $a = Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource -GatewayClusterId $clusterDS.ClusterId -GatewayClusterDatasourceId $clusterDS.Id 
     
     $clusterName = $clusterDS.ClusterName
     $DatasourceName = $clusterDS.DatasourceName
     $DatasourceType = $clusterDS.DatasourceType
     $ConnectionDetails = $clusterDS.ConnectionDetails
     $ClusterId = $clusterDS.ClusterId
     $clusterDSID = $clusterDS.Id

     $clusterName, $DatasourceName , $DatasourceType , $ConnectionDetails , $ClusterId, $clusterDSID
     
}

Another thing that I have tried to do without success is filter by name
foreach ($clusterDS in Get-DataGatewayCluster | Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource | where-object {$_.ClusterName -eq "xxx"})
This would allow me to filter based on the cluster name rather than pull them all out.

Your foreach is returning an array of values to the output stream - replace everything inside the { ... } (but not the braces themselves) with [pscustomobject] @{ "ClusterName" = $clusterDS.ClusterName; "DataSourceName" = $clusterDS.DataSourceName; ... etc ... } to return PSCustomObjects instead.

foreach ( $clusterDS in Get-DataGatewayCluster | Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource | where-object {$_.ClusterName -eq "xxx"} )
{
    $hash = [Ordered]@{}

    $hash.status = (Get-DataGatewayClusterDatasource -GatewayClusterId $clusterDS.ClusterId -GatewayClusterDatasourceId $clusterDS.Id ).Status
    $hash.clusterName = $clusterDS.ClusterName
    $hash.DatasourceName = $clusterDS.DatasourceName
    $hash.DatasourceType = $clusterDS.DatasourceType
    $hash.ConnectionDetails = $clusterDS.ConnectionDetails
    $hash.ClusterId = $clusterDS.ClusterId
    $hash.clusterDSID = $clusterDS.Id

    [PSCustomObject]$hash

}

